# The opacity for Windows PowerShell is remembered on Enterprise edition, not Professional

Tags: windows-10, powershell

My personal preference is to have the opacity of the Windows PowerShell window set to 90%. I have it set that way on my work desktop and work laptop. Windows remembers this setting, so every time I go into PowerShell, the opacity is set to 90%.

However, Windows PowerShell on my personal desktop and laptop does not remember that. I have to set it each time I open a Windows PowerShell window.

My work desktop and work laptop are both Windows 10 Enterprise machines. My personal desktop and personal laptop are both Windows 10 Professional machines. So, just verifying, is the ability to remember the opacity setting for a Windows PowerShell window something that only Windows 10 Enterprise can do? That no other versions of Windows 10 will remember that setting?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 is each machine running?  I wasn't able to reproduce on my Windows 10 Professional machine.

Comment: Good question, Ramhound. My personal desktop and laptop are both running 1809. My work desktop and laptop are both running 1803.

Comment: You should include that information in your question instead of a comment.  However, the opacity of the command prompt (which by default is a PowerShell prompt) isn't a feature of either of those versions, so that difference is unlikely the cause of the behavior.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't thought of that. But since saving the opacity value isn't a part of either versions, I suspect the difference is between I'm using Enterprise at work and Professional at home. Thank you, Ramhound.